# Replace multiple things at once in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to replace multiple things at once in MySQL?

It feels kinda clumsy doing this

```
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( myField, 'å', 'a' ) , 'Å', 'A' ) , 'Ø', 'O' ) , 'ø', 'o' ) , 'æ', 'a' ) , 'Æ', 'A' )
```

Comment: Are looking for the equivalent of the Oracle SQL [TRANSLATE() function](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Char-Functions/UsingtheTRANSLATEFunctiontoencodeanddecode.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. There's really no need to elaborate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [user defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html) to do this, but it's probably something I would put in a layer other than the database.

The database is optimised for the stuff it needs to do, data extraction/sorting/grouping and so on.

While it *can* do some manipulation of data within a column, that's not really its primary purpose (leave that to the presentation or other layers).

If you *must* do it within the DBMS, consider doing it with a separate column holding the modified data, and having that maintained with an insert/update trigger. This will at least ensure the cost is incurred only when the data changes, rather than every time you look at it. In other words, it will amortise the cost across all selects.